# Seemingly duplicate trusted GPG keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository, gnupg

I was recently dealing with [this bug in apt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540) and was trying to figure out which `.gpg` files I could remove to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` to stop the `W: GPG error: NO_PUBKEY` error I was getting with `apt-get update`.

So, I went and ran `ls` in the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory, to see if there were any old keys for repositories I had removed. While doing that, I noticed this:

```
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp.gpg
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp.gpg~
otto-kesselgulasch_ubuntu_gimp.gpg
otto-kesselgulasch_ubuntu_gimp.gpg~
phablet-team-tools.gpg
phablet-team-tools.gpg~
phablet-team_ubuntu_tools.gpg
phablet-team_ubuntu_tools.gpg~
```

when I ran `ls`.

There seem to be duplicate entries (`diff`-ing the _ubuntu_ and non _ubuntu_ version of the files returns nothing) of some of the `.gpg` key files.

Why do I have the seemingly duplicate entries and which (if any) can I safely delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are left-overs from before and after your upgrade: verify these with the same files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and look which files in that directory contain any meaningful data.

The empty files in `sources.list.d` and their counterparts in `trusted.gpg.d` can be safely deleted.