# Why does ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d list key files twice?

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

This happens in Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Look at this:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
insgesamt 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  392 2024-02-03 17:36 atareao-ubuntu-atareao.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2024-02-03 17:36 atareao-ubuntu-atareao.gpg~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1162 2024-02-03 17:37 giuspen-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2024-02-03 17:37 giuspen-ubuntu-ppa.gpg~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2794 2021-03-27 00:35 ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1733 2021-03-27 00:35 ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  396 2024-02-03 17:30 yktooo-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2024-02-03 17:30 yktooo-ubuntu-ppa.gpg~
$
```

**Why are most of those key files listed twice**, the other time with the name with an appended ~ and length zero?

N.B.: In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-ubuntu-atareao-jammy.list` there are two entries, one for a deb URL and one for a deb-src URL. The same holds for the other files with those zero-length almost siblings.

**What do these entries mean? Why does Thunar not show them?  Can I safely remove those files with length zero?**

BTW:

1. Thunar does not show those second files with length 0.
2. I saw the similar question [Seemingly duplicate trusted GPG keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692256/seemingly-duplicate-trusted-gpg-keys-in-etc-apt-trusted-gpg-d), however it deals with identical files with those ~ and they could be deleted.

Comment: The ~ appended is usually the "backup" copy of an edited file -- the version before the edit.

Comment: ... also for `gpg`, the tilde `~` is appended to temporary files during the key generation (although the permissions on those files suggest being copied by some editor as backups) ... The key thing here is that those files with the trailing tilde are not used as keys and since they look empty as well then they can be safely moved/deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I removed them with ```sudo rm -i /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*~
```. But why does Thunar not show these files? Are they hidden like files whose names start with a dot?